# How to create a Firestore document if the user is new in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need to sign in users into my website using signInWithRedirect I'm using GoolgeAuthProvider, I also need to create a document on Firestore that holds some information about users. Now my problem is that I need to check if the user that has signed in with Google has signed in for the first time which means he signed up using Google and then decide if the document has to be created or not.
the operationType property of the response object is always "signIn" even if the user has signed in for the first time.

I tried checking if the creationTime and lastSignInTime were the same which I thought would indicate the user is new, but even after a few signs in those two remain the same.

Comment: Why don't you just try to read the document every time, then create it if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: I'd indeed go with the approach Doug suggested. But in general, if you tried something and can't get it to work, it is *much* more likely that we can help if you show us the [minimal, complete code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Moreover, I'd suggest you use the user's Firebase authenticator UUID as the document id, so it will be easier to find it in Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the provider is, if the sign-in is successful when a user signs in for the first time in Firebase, then you get back, as a result, a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential) object which contains a [user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredentialuser) property.

If you want to know if the user is new, meaning it signs in for the first time, then you can compare the values of two fields, [creationTime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata#usermetadatacreationtime) and [lastSignInTime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata#usermetadatalastsignintime) which exist inside the [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usermetadata) object. If the difference is not bigger than a just few milliseconds, then it means that the user was just created.

It's true that you can check if a document that corresponds to the user already exists in a collection, but that implies a read operation in Firestore. If that doesn't bother you, then you can go ahead with checking the existence of the document in Firestore.

Comment: Hey Shaban. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?